# MUI DatePicker Error in production after migrating from CRA to Vite

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app, vite

My project runs fine when using CRA. After deciding to migrate to Vite, all is well on the dev server. However, when I was in production, I encountered a problem on every page where I imported { DatePicker } from @mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker. The page suddenly goes blank and an error appears which I don't understand which looks like the one below.

[image]

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I have the same behavior, weird i will try the version 6 of mui-x

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @FatehMohamed Yes.. the problem is solved by downgrading @mui/x-date-pickers to version ^5.0.0-alpha.1

Comment: Check my answer, for me it was related to vite version

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in vite itself , you have to update vite to the latest version and the issue will be fixed

```
npm i vite@latest
```